# WCF Service Application deploy in IIS 8.5 on Windows 10 keep loading forever without error code

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, amazon-ec2

I create a default WCF Service Application, build it success and run OK on Visual Studio 2015
But when i copy this project to IIS, it keep loading forever. I've turn on HttpActivation feature and set Web.config with IIS_IUSRS permission but not change anything. Any could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days i found solution for my problem: Set WCF Service folder with IIS_IUSRS Permission and IUSR Permission (may be just need for Web.config file)